# Usi dell'espressione "via crucis"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, single-words, phrase-choice, phrases

Una mia amica ha usato l'espressione "via crucis" per descrivere una situazione dove varie persone in vari negozi le avevano dato delle cose e lei doveva passare in quei luoghi uno per uno per pagare i debiti.

Però una volta guardato nel dizionario trovato questa definizione:

> 1 relig. Esercizio devoto che consiste nel recitare preghiere e nel
>   fare meditazione davanti a ciascuna delle quattordici stazioni che
>   ricordano episodi della Passione di Cristo; estens. la
>   rappresentazione pittorica o in bassorilievo delle stazioni 2 fig.
>   Serie interminabile di sofferenze: la sua vita è stata un'autentica
>   via crucis

Qualcuno può per caso spiegarmi come sono legati questo due usi dell'espressione e farmi magari altri esempi? Ci sono per caso anche altri significati?

Grazie.

Comment: Quale dizionario? Non esiste *il* dizionario. Citi le tue fonti per piacere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Napoli (dove vivo) e più in generale nel sud Italia, l'espressione "via crucis" è utilizzata in quelle situazioni in cui si rende necessario seguire delle tappe obbligate (intesa principalmente come situazione non piacevole), un po' come avviene nella processione del rito cattolico, dove si compiono delle fermate in cui vengono recitate le preghiere in commemorazione delle sofferenze di Cristo nel percorso verso la crocifissione.

Potrebbe essere tradotta come "cammino penitenziale".

Es: alle pagelle di fine trimestre, ci tocca la via crucis con i professori (intesa come la [dolorosa] tappa fatta ad ogni professore per avere la valutazione dell'alunno).

Ovviamente l'esempio di sopra funziona solo nel caso in cui l'alunno non sia andato particolarmente bene durante l'anno scolastico :D

Answer (score 6):

"Via crucis" è un'espressione latina con la quale si indica il cammino che Cristo percorse con addosso la croce sulla quale venne poi crocefisso. Secondo la leggenda, Cristo subì torture e percosse durante il percorso, che si concluse con la crocefissione e dunque la morte.

Letteralmente, indica le rappresentazioni che vengono tenute dai cattolici al giorno d'oggi, in memoria di tali sofferenze.

In via metaforica, rappresenta una qualsiasi attività definita da un percorso difficile al punto tale da essere stato considerato una sofferenza.